# Error in Nuget in VS 2010

Tags: nuget

I am getting the below error when i try to open "Add Package Manager" GUI in Nuget. 
But i am able to add/remove package successfully using Powershell console.
I am using visual studio 2010 Ultimate RtmRel.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Any idea why the GUI is not working ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Known bug:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/580

See the comments for some workarounds